# Removing a node from a list using a for

Tags: c#, list, split

Here is what I have done:

```
// this is an example of my function, the string and the remover should be variables
string delimeter = ",";
string remover="4";
string[] separator = new string[] { "," };
List<String> List = "1,2,3,4,5,6".Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if(List[i]==remover)
        List.RemoveAt(i);
}
string allStrings = (List.Aggregate((i, j) => i + delimeter + j));
return allStrings;
```

The problem is the retruned string is the same as the originial one, same as "1,2,3,4,5,6". the "4" is still in it.

How to fix it?

**EDIT:**

the solution was that i didnt check the last node of the list in that for, it doesnt seem like that in the example because it was an example i gave just now

Comment: Just a side note: You have `i < List.Count - 1`, but that would never hit the last item. Is that what you intended?

Comment: You have off by one error and what @Bradley said..

Answer (score 5):

When you remove items from a list like this you should make your for loop run in reverse, from  highest index to lowest.

If you go from lowest to highest you will end up shifting items down as they are removed and this will skip items.  Running it in reverse does not have this issue.

Comment: Since the OP's example doesn't have two `4`s in a row, that won't bit him here though.

Comment: the was a nice tip, i found my bug Thanks!

Comment: @Cooper This is *a* bug, but it's not the bug that caused your code to not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your code, as it stands, produces the expected output.  When running it it will return `1,2,3,5,6`.  If it doesn't it's due to a bug in how you call this method.

That's not to say that you don't have problems.

When you remove an item you still increment the current index, so you skip checking the item after any item you remove.

While there are a number of solutions, the best solution here is to use the `RemoveAll` method of `List`.  Not only does it ensure that all items are evaluated, but it can do so way more efficiently.  Removing an item from a list means shifting all of the items over by one.  `RemoveAll` can do all of that shifting at the end, which is way more efficient if a lot of items are removed.

Another bug that you have is that your `for` loop doesn't check the last item at all, ever.

On a side note, you shouldn't use `Aggregate` to join a bunch of strings together given a delimiter.  It's *extremely* inefficient as you need to copy all of the data from the first item into an intermediate string when adding the second, then both of those to a new string when adding the third, then all three of *those* to a new string when creating a fourth, and so on.  Instead you should use `string.Join(delimeter, List);`, which is not only *way* more efficient, but is way easier to write and semantically represents exactly what you're trying to do.  Win win win.

We can now re-write the method as:

```
string delimeter = ",";
string remover = "4";
List<String> List = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
    .Split(new[] { delimeter }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
List.RemoveAll(n => n == remover);
return string.Join(delimeter, List);
```

Another option is to avoid creating a list just to remove items from it and then aggregate the data again.  We can instead just take the sequence of items that we have, pull out only the items that we want to keep, rather than removing the items we don't want to keep, and then aggregate those.  This is functionally the same, but remove the needless effort of building up a list and removing items, pulling out mechanism from the requirements:

```
string delimeter = ",";
string remover = "4";
var items = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
        .Split(new[] { delimeter }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .Where(n => n != remover);
return string.Join(delimeter, items);
```

Comment: my bug was that i didint check the last node in the for, i dosent seem like that in the example because it's an example i gave just now, thanks alot any way

Answer (score 1):

Use this for remove

```
  list.RemoveAll(f => f==remover);
```

Comment: I think this is the solution to the problem, since their intencios is clear all items that meet a certain condition. 
He uses a loop, which is incorrect, because when you delete an item, the list is altered and its index becomes invalid. 
The List class provides the method to perform this operation without using any loop.